# What is the simplest way to declare an array in javascript, having elements, 1, 2, 3....n

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to declare an array having integer elements 1 to n, where n can be 100 or greater. So, its obvious that I don't want to add all integers (1 to 100) manually.

Can someone suggest me the simplest way to do this in javascript?
I think there should be something like this: [1..n], but its not working.

EDIT:

MORE CLARIFICATION OF REQUIREMENT:

I need this: `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,....,100]` but I don't want to declare like this where I have to write every element manually. I need something better option to do this.

Comment: What do you mean? What have you tried? Etc. Point of clarity: arrays are a JavaScript concept, not jQuery - no such thing as a jQuery array.

Comment: Did you mean `javascript array` ?

Comment: yeah sorry, in arrays in javascript

Comment: @RAJ..., `Taz` already answered what you need.

Comment: My example does exactly what you want. First index is `i[0]`, last `i[9]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this like:

```
var i = new Array(10);
for ( var j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
    i[j] = j + 1;
}
```

Just create an array and fill them with a for loop. You don’t have to declare the `var` at the beginning.

[**Check This Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cUKhm/) `See the result in the console`

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the simplest way, so it could be as some of many ways

```
var arr=[1,2,3];
alert(arr[0]); // 1
```

or

```
var arr=[];
arr[0]=1;
alert(arr[0]); // 1
```

See [Taz's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503785/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-declare-an-array-in-javascript-having-elements-1/11503862#11503862) answer he has answered what you need, you can go with it.

Answer (score -2):

If you use underscore.js, I suggest this useful function : http://underscorejs.org/#range

```
_.range(10);
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you play with arrays in your app, you can find other useful usages for underscore.js.